Randomly generated matrices have full rank
I was performing the exercise 4.2.19 from my text book: Fundamentals of Matrix Computations by David S Watkins.

Performing this experiment multiple times I realized that the lowest singular values always comes out to be non zero (significantly higher that unit round off), confirming that input matrices are full rank.
I wanted to understand why are these randomly generated matrices full rank? Is it because of some property of normal distribution or true for any other distribution as well? (I tried with uniform distribution as well, and got similar results)

It is similar to saying "a parallelogram has zero volume"

Out of curiosity, what does the distribution of the smallest singular value look like?

The question is similar to what suggested by @Another User
Reiterating my understanding of the same solution here.
Suppose we are generating a matrix $A_{nxm}$ where $m\leq n$. Assume first $m-1$ columns are linearly independent. We are interested to calculate the probability that the vector $a_m$ can be represented in some linear combination of the vectors $\{a_1, a_2,...a_m\}$. Which is equivalent to saying that the set of vectors $\{a_1, a_2,...a_m\}$ lie on a $m-1$ hyperplane in the $m$ dimensional subspace.
Since the distribution chosen is continuous, the probability that it takes a constant value in $m^{th}$ dimension(or precisely constant value in the direction of $m^{th}$ basis vector) is $0$.
An illustration of this consider $m=3$ and distribution as $U(0,1)$. If it was the case that columns were linearly dependent that it would create a plane/line in the $3D$ space, however the possible set of values form a unit cube in the $3D$ space. And since "volume of such a parallelogram / line is $0$" we can say that probability of forming a linearly dependent set is $0$, thus giving us a full rank matrix.
To reply @A rural reader's comment above, I used the following code to generate a histogram plot
last_sing_value=[];
for i=1:1000
    A=randn(100,100); 
    last_sing_value=[last_sing_value;min(svd(A))];
end
histogram(last_sing_value, 50)
xticks(0:0.025:0.3);
xlabel('Last Singular Values');
ylabel('Frequency');

The results shows a skewed distribution closer to 0 (with the minimum of these values having order of $10^{-4}$):

